# HttpURLConnection - Why request is sent only when we are reading from connection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serversocket

Why is that when we try reading something from the connection that the request payload is sent to the request.In below code if connection.getResponseCode(); is present, request is recieved by server but if its not present, request is not reaching/being sent.

It even doesnt throw any exception if the connection response code is commented below.

This is based on Java 8.

```
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL url=new URL("http://...");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String request="{\"language\":\"english\"}";
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(500);
        connection.setReadTimeout(300);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

        byte[] payload = request.getBytes();
        outputStream.write(payload);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        //If commented request is not reaching server controller
        //if uncommented , request is reaching
        connection.getResponseCode();
```